# React setState changing different object in state

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my initial state of component

```
this.state = {
  date: "",
  students: "",
  attendance: {}
}
```

On **ComponentDidMount** I am getting date and students array from a reducer.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { date, students } = this.props;
    const todayDate = this.getFormattedDate(date);

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      date: todayDate,
      students,
      attendance: {
        ...prevState.attendance,
        [todayDate]: students
      }
    }), () => console.log('CDM', this.state));
}
```

I have a checkbox which when touched should update `attendance[todayDate]` and update property `checked` of a particular student.

In render I am mapping over attendance[date] and returning JSX

```
<CheckBox
   checked={student.checked}
   onPress={() => this.takeAttendance(student.id)}
   containerStyle={styles.checkboxStyle}
/>
```

The checkHandler

```
takeAttendance(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      attendance: {
        ...prevState.attendance,
        [this.state.date]: prevState.attendance[this.state.date].map(
          obj => (obj.id === id ? Object.assign(obj, { checked: !obj.checked }) : obj)
        )
      }
    }), () => console.log('TA', this.state));
  }
```

So it's working correctly. The property `checked` of a student in attendance[date] is getting changed but its also changing the checked value in students piece of state. I do not understand why it is also changing the students piece of state and not just attendance[date].

Added video for reference. [Streamable](https://streamable.com/u1o8a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm looks all correct, may be try addressing the `this.state.date` to `prevState.date`?

```
attendance: {
        ...prevState.attendance,
        [prevState.date]: prevState.attendance[prevState.date].map(
          obj => (obj.id === id ? Object.assign(obj, { checked: !obj.checked }) : obj)
        )
      }
```

Edit:
Could be issue with `this.setState(prevState => ({ date: todayDate, students,`. You are setting the students same as `[todayDate]: students`.
Add property checked to each individual student and stored that in attendance[date].

Comment: No my students property is still getting changed. I am gonna add a fiddle

Comment: Yes please, that would be great.

Comment: I am unable to add a fiddle as it's a react native project but I have added a video which shows the problem. [Streamable](https://streamable.com/u1o8a)

Comment: Students Array values are not changing on [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@sl-a-sh/attendance) but as you can see in the video it's chaging. I have the exact same code except I am getting the states from redux and then saving to component state.

Comment: Okay so I commented my componentDidMount and added the values directly in component state instead of getting from redux and its working fine. Do you know why?

Comment: Could be issue with `this.setState(prevState => ({
      date: todayDate,
      students,`. You are setting the students same as `[todayDate]: students`

Comment: Ok yea that worked I kept students as the array returned from redux and I mapped over the array adding property `checked` to each individual student and stored that in attendance[date]. Thanks you can update your answer

Answer (score 0):

try to check deep clone object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone